# Casting void* to char* in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, binary-search

I have to code an abstract binary search function for any data type with compare function as a parameter. I didn't know what to do with void, because it's impossible to use pointer arithmetic. Then I saw standard qsort function and did like that.  And the question is what is going on when happens conversion from `void*` to `char*`? Why does it works?

```
void *bin_srch(void *a, size_t n, size_t bs, void *x, int (*cmp)(const void *a, const void *b))
{
    size_t f = 0, l = n;

    if(!n) return NULL;

    while (f < l)
    {
        size_t m = f/2 + l/2;
        char *mid = (char*)a + m*bs;

        if (cmp(x, mid) <= 0)
            l = m;
        else
            f = m + 1;
    }

    char *t = (char*)a + l*bs;

    if (!cmp(t, x))
        return t;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to cast anything to `char *` - all the pointers in your function should be `void *`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, why'd it be UB? `char *` can be used to access any other type, isn't it?

Comment: @ChrisTurner *all the pointers in your function should be `void *`*  How does one do pointer arithmetic on `void *` pointers?

Comment: @AndrewHenle pointers are all the same size regardless of type, so you'd do them the same as any other pointer ie   `myvoidptr++`

Comment: @ChrisTurner I think you made a mistake. You can't increment a `void*` pointer - it just doesn't work, and it's not clear what it would do even if it did work -- `ptr++` increments the pointer by `sizeof(*ptr)` bytes. That doesn't make sense for a `void*` pointer, since `void` is not a valid type on its own.

Comment: @ChrisTurner *pointers are all the same size regardless of type*  Where is that from?  *`myvoidptr++`*  Umm, no.  Pointer arithmetic on `void *` violates [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  6.5.6-2 states "For addition,  either  both  operands  shall  have  arithmetic  type,  or  **one  operand  shall  be  a
pointer to a complete object type** and the other shall have integer type."

Comment: @PaulHankin I'd suggest _complete_ instead of _valid_. :)

Comment: If I've made a mistake, I'm not alone because gcc has no problems compiling code that does `void *` pointer arithmetic of the kind found in the OP

Comment: @ChrisTurner *gcc has no problems compiling code that does `void *` pointer arithmetic*  All that means is GCC is not C standard-compliant.

Answer (score 3):

It works, because, `char *` can *alias* any other type.

Quoting from `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> [....] When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>   the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

Using this property, casting to `char *` enables the ability to perform pointer arithmetics using the (casted) pointer as operand.

As mentioned in the same spec (*with my emphasis*), chapter §6.5.6/p2

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
>   **pointer to a complete object type** and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is
>   equivalent to adding 1.)

and, p3

> For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible complete
>     object types; or
> - the left operand is a **pointer to a complete object type** and the right operand has
>     integer type.

which needs the pointer operand to be a pointer-to-complete type, which `void` is not and `char` is.

lastly, referring chapter §6.2.5/p19

> The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that
>   cannot be completed.

Answer (score 1):

You basically answered your question yourself. The only reason this code contains conversions to `char *` is to use byte-based pointer arithmetic in expressions like

```
char *mid = (char*)a + m*bs;
```

I.e. to calculate the location of array element specified in terms of index `m` and byte-size of the element `bs`. When you convert to `char *` the resultant pointer points to the same location as the original `void *` pointer, except that now you can apply pointer arithemtic to it.